# Specify default value in Hibernate's XML configuration file

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm configuring Hibernate via the mapping configuration file.

```
<class name="Person" table="person">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="long"/>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
    <property name="age" column="age" type="integer"/>
</class>
```

How do I set `age` to be nullable and default to null?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<property name="age" type="integer">
  <column name="age" not-null="false" default="null" />
</property>
```

Comment: isn't `default="null"` the same as just specifying no default at all?

Comment: Yes it is. I wrote it purely to demonstrate how to specify the default value. Normally you would make the property a nullable integer so NHibernate would figure out the nullable by itself.