# Hibernate. Add default column value after column creation

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there a way to set a default value for existing entries after the column has been created using Hibernate?

Found that the operation could be done manually by:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee 
ADD DEFAULT('SANDNES') FOR CityBorn
```

but is there a way to do something using hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the annotation

```
@ColumnDefault("SANDNES")
```

like specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107554/define-default-column-value-with-annotations-in-hibernate%201)

or the xml-fragment

```
  <column name="CityBorn" default="SANDNES" />
```

like specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610211/specify-default-value-in-hibernates-xml-configuration-file)

If you want to let Hibernate re-create your databse, you have to specify hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update, but this is not the recommended way for production (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production))
Normally one would use a third-party tool for schema-migration (e.g liquibase or flyway). The possibilities of hbm2ddl (used by Hibernate) are limited.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried this way. Works only on new entries. The idea is to set a default value of a column to the existing values in the db.

Comment: You mean updare all records within the db, or setting the (java) field of the entity to a default value if the column is empty?

Comment: Just realized what i was hoping to achieve with the "update existing entries" :) Yea, the idea was to update all of the records(or this could be done from the entity declaration?)

Answer (score 0):

That would be the way in hibernate.

```
@Column(name="CityBorn", columnDefinition="default 'SANDNESS'")
private String cityBorn;
```

Comment: The idea is to set the default value for the existing entries of the table.